# Python xpath and conditionals

Tags: python, xpath, nested

I'm trying to find all elements that are h3 class="threadtitle" and within this element, if there is the text "NSW" return the value of the < a> element.

```
<h3 class="threadtitle">
    <img border="0" alt="MARKET PLACE/AUCTIONS" src="vbcover/ibid/images/auction_open.png" title="MARKET PLACE/AUCTIONS">
    <span class="prefix understate">
        <b>
            <font size="2" face="arial" color="#0000FF">NSW</font>
        </b>
    </span>
    <a id="thread_title_1234" class="title" href="showthread.php?t=1234">Banana man</a>
</h3>
```

This is what I have so far:
I can find individual elements like this:

```
import requests
from lxml import etree, html
response '''
<h3 class="threadtitle">
    <img border="0" alt="MARKET PLACE/AUCTIONS" src="vbcover/ibid/images/auction_open.png" title="MARKET PLACE/AUCTIONS">
    <span class="prefix understate">
        <b>
            <font size="2" face="arial" color="#0000FF">NSW</font>
        </b>
    </span>
    <a id="thread_title_1234" class="title" href="showthread.php?t=1234">Banana man</a>
</h3>
'''
tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
test = tree.xpath("//font[text()='NSW']")
#or
test2 = tree.xpath("//h3[@class='threadtitle']")

for i in test:
    print i

NSW
```

But I don't know how to combine these.

The above example should return 'Banana man'

Comment: Do you know exactly, that text must be in h3/span/b/font element? And needed `<a>` elem - is the last child of `<h3>`, or h3 will always have only one `<a>`?

Comment: Yes they would all be the same as above. All good, Joel's answer works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this xpath:

```
//h3[@class='threadtitle'][descendant::font/text() = 'NSW']/a/text()
```